# Casting multidimensional array from bundle.putsSerializable

Tags: java, android, arrays

I was trying to pass a 2D array from my activity A with this code:

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("Qna", g);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
```

and I was trying to get the 2D array in my Activity B with this code:

```
QnA = (String[][]) b.getSerializable("Qna");
```

but i get the error like this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.danbrianarenas.letsreview/com.example.danbrianarenas.letsreview.ShowScore}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String[][]

Comment: Can anyone tell my why my question is getting negative votes? O.o

Comment: Because you're asking a question with almost no useful context. People like questions that are answerable.

Comment: What are you passing to your `Activity`? Show the code where you create the `Intent`.

Comment: So you're saying that this question is not answerable? please tell me ... what didnt you understand in my question? I can edit it. i just need to confirm if that code is allowed.

Comment: i was passing a 2d array @Bryan

Comment: You don't need to post the whole app, but do post a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 I have edited it. perhaps the added code will help understand the question. please answer ASAP. I really need it.

Comment: Nested arrays (i.e. `String[][]`) *are* `Serializable`, therefore one of the possible reasons you are not *receiving* a `String[][]` is because you are not *actually* sending a `String[][]`.

Comment: By the way, we are all volunteers here. By saying ASAP, it isn't helping you or us. For more information, [read here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/2308683)

Comment: @cricket_007 yes yes ... Sorry for that. I was really frustrated after having that bug for a week.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is caused by the way 2 dimensional arrays are serialized and deserialized. You have to rebuild the 2 dimensional array yourself by looping through the elements of the `Object[]`.

**You need to replace this line:**

```
QnA = (String[][]) b.getSerializable("Qna");
```

**With this:**

```
String[][] qnaArray = null;

Object[] serializableArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Qna");

if (serializableArray != null) {

    qnaArray = new String[serializableArray.length][];

    for(int index = 0; index < serializableArray.length; index++){

        qnaArray[index] = (String[]) serializableArray[index];

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but i think i found a better solution. Correct me if im wrong, but I remember that you can use variables from different classes. I made an object of Activity A class in my Activity B from there i just put

Comment: Activity_A acta = new Activity A(); then QnA = acta.g; where g is my 2D array. what do you think?

Comment: You should never create a new instance of an Activity. You should always use the Intent system to create a new Activity. I would not recommend the solution you are proposing but as it is your code you should use what you are comfortable with.